# Click Like to post this to your profile

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-like

I am trying to add a facebook "like" button to an events website.

I created the button on facebook and tested it on facebook - it worked and posted the event to my facebook page. I then pasted the code into the event page and tried to "like" the event.

After clicking "like" I got the "confirm" popup and the text read "Click Like to post this to your profile". After clicking nothing was posted to my facebook page.

In the popup window I expected to see "post this to your facebook page - not "Click Like to post this to your profile".

Does anyone have any idea why it works from facebook but not from my webpage?

Code example:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=urltoeventpage&send=false&layout=button_count&width=125&show_faces=false&font&colorscheme=light&action=like&height=21"
  scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
  style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:125px; height:21px;"
  allowTransparency="true">
</iframe>
```

In the example above the urltoeventpage is a urlencoded URL.

Additional info. I also created a Tweet button, a pin it button and a Google plus 1 button. They all worked right out of the box. Only the Facebook button won't work.

Comment: Can You be a little bit more specific? Could You post some code examples?

Comment: I managed to work around this problem by using the facebook share api. <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={urlref}" onclick="window.open(this.href, 'share',
'left=20,top=20,width=626,height=436,toolbar=no,resizable=0'); return false;" >share</a>

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={urlref}"
  onclick="window.open(this.href, 
  'share','left=20,top=20,width=626,height=436,toolbar=no,resizable=0');
  return false;"
>share</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only time I achieved a confirmation screen with a like button was when i was using a facebook test-user...